# Error while running tomcat Ant task for the site

Tags: broadleaf-commerce, maven-ant-tasks

I had setup broadleaf commerce project with mysql database with successive MAVEN install. When i am going to run ant task for tomcat it gives errors like this

```
The archive: /home/yogesh/Downloads/.eclipse%20(3)/plugins
/org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64_3.104.0.v20150528-0211.jar
which is referenced by the classpath, does not exist.`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try redownloading and re-installing Eclipse. Also make sure that you are using the latest release version, which is Eclipse Mars.